# Modulus of a complex function whose inverse is equal to its conjugate

Tags: complex-analysis

I am studying a paper with a function defined on the complex plane. In the paper it is shown that the complex conjugate of the function is equal to the reciprocal of the function, on a particular subset of the complex plane. The paper then states that the above result implies that the modulus of the function must be 1 on the given subset.

Excuse my relative lack of knowledge of complex analysis, but is there any theorem that states that a complex function whose reciprocal is equal to its conjugate has a modulus of 1?

Comment: Instead of inverse, do you mean reciprocal (i.e. $1/f$)?

Comment: what is the range of "the particular set" that defines the equality of conjugate and the inverse? is it the unit ball?

Comment: If you mean that the function satisfies $\overline{f(z)} = 1/f(z)$, then this follows simply by multiplying that equation by $f(z)$. (Note that this function cannot be holomorphic unless it is constant, so this isn't really a problem in complex analysis.)

Comment: Yes, the original question should read reciprocal rather than inverse. It has been edited to make this change. Thanks